# Code not looping over all products of a given category

Tags: plugin-wp-e-commerce

I try to fetch all products for a given category managed by the wp e-commerce plugin, but the code I use is not looping all the products returned. All the code is a sort of API to look for products and return them later to an extern application with JSON.

First , this is all the code I use:

```
$catid = $_REQUEST['catid'];//get the category id from the url
$term1 = get_term($catid,'wpsc_product_category');
getdetails($term1->slug,$term1->term_id,$host,$term1->parent);
echo '----------------------------'.'<br />';
echo $term1->slug .'<br />';
echo $term1->term_id.'<br />';
echo $term1->parent.'<br />';
echo '----------------------------'.'<br />';
function getdetails($id,$tid,$host,$cid)
{
     $wpec_product_categories = get_terms( 'wpsc_product_category', 'hide_empty=0&slug='.$id);
    echo '-------this is a stack of the product category array--------<br />';
    var_dump($wpec_product_categories).'<br />';
    echo '-------------------------------------------<br />';

    if($wpec_product_categories[0]->count != 0)
    {

    echo 'count is '.$wpec_product_categories[0]->count.'<br />';//here the correct number of products. So, so far all is going good.
     foreach($wpec_product_categories as $wpec_categories){
           $wpec_term_id = $wpec_categories->term_id;
            $wpec_term_name = $wpec_categories->name;
            $wpec_term_slug = $wpec_categories->slug;
            $wpec_term_parent = $wpec_categories->parent;
            echo '<br />--------------------<br />';
            echo  $wpec_term_name.'<br />';
            echo  $wpec_term_slug.'<br />';
            echo  $wpec_term_parent.'<br />';
            echo '<br />--------------------<br />';


                                    $wpec_args = array(
                                   'post_status' => 'publish',
                                   'post_type'   => 'wpsc-product',
                                   'wpsc_product_category' => $wpec_term_slug
                                  );
                                  $wpec_categoryProducts = new WP_Query($wpec_args);

        while ($wpec_categoryProducts->have_posts()) : $wpec_categoryProducts->the_post();
             echo '<br />---------------------||||||--------------------<br />';
             echo 'Content:'.$wpec_categoryProducts->the_post().'<br />';   
             echo '<br />---------------------||||||--------------------<br />';

             echo 'Product wholesale price: '.wpsc_the_product_price().'<br />';

           $selthumb ="SELECT p.*, pm.* FROM wp_posts as p, wp_postmeta as pm WHERE  pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' AND pm.meta_value = p.ID AND p.post_parent = '".wpsc_the_product_id()."' AND p.post_type = 'attachment'";
         $resthumb = mysql_query($selthumb);
         $rowthumb = mysql_fetch_array($resthumb);
          $img = stripslashes($rowthumb['guid']) ;
              if($img != '')
              {
                  $path =  $img;
              }
              else
              {
                  $selimg = "SELECT * FROM wp_wpsc_meta WHERE meta_key = 'image' AND object_id = ".$tid;
                  $resimg = mysql_query($selimg);
                  $rowimg = mysql_fetch_array($resimg);
                  if($rowimg != '')
                  {
                      $path = "http://".stripcslashes($host."/wp-content/uploads/wpsc/category_images/".$rowimg['meta_value']);

                  }
                  else
                  {
                       $selimg = "SELECT * FROM wp_wpsc_meta WHERE meta_key = 'image' AND object_id = ".$cid;
                       $resimg = mysql_query($selimg);
                        $rowimg = mysql_fetch_array($resimg);
                        if($rowimg != '')
                        {
                            $path = "http://".stripcslashes($host."/wp-content/uploads/wpsc/category_images/".$rowimg['meta_value']);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                             $selpimg = "SELECT tx.*,m.* FROM wp_term_taxonomy tx,wp_wpsc_meta m WHERE tx.term_id = '".$cid."' AND m.meta_key = 'image' AND m.object_id = tx.parent";
                            $respimg = mysql_query($selpimg);
                            $rowpimg = mysql_fetch_array($respimg);
                            if($rowpimg != '')
                            {
                                $path = "http://".stripcslashes($host."/wp-content/uploads/wpsc/category_images/".$rowpimg['meta_value']);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $path= "false";
                            }
                        }
                  }
              }

              $selcolor = "SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = '".wpsc_the_product_id()."' AND meta_key = '_wpsc_color'";
              $rescolor = mysql_query($selcolor);
              $rowcolor = mysql_fetch_array($rescolor);

              $selsize = "SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = '".wpsc_the_product_id()."' AND meta_key = '_wpsc_size'";
              $ressize = mysql_query($selsize);
              $rowsize = mysql_fetch_array($ressize);

              $selprice = "SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = '".wpsc_the_product_id()."' AND meta_key = '_wpsc_special_price'";
              $resprice = mysql_query($selprice);
              $rowprice = mysql_fetch_array($resprice);

              $selmanu = "SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = '".wpsc_the_product_id()."' AND meta_key = '_wpsc_manufacturer'";
              $resmanu = mysql_query($selmanu);
              $rowmenu = mysql_fetch_array($resmanu);

              $product_data = get_post_custom( wpsc_the_product_id() );
              $product_data['meta'] = maybe_unserialize( $product_data );

              $image = stripslashes(sb_get_images_for_product( wpsc_the_product_id() ));

              $list = explode(",",$image);


             $arr[] = array("Product ID" => wpsc_the_product_id(),"Product Title" => wpsc_the_product_title(), "Product Description" => wpsc_the_product_description(), "Product Wholesale Price" => wpsc_the_product_price(), "Product Sale Price" => '$'.$rowprice['meta_value'], "Category Id" => $wpec_term_id,"Category Name" => $wpec_term_name,"Product Image" => $path, "Product Sub Images" => $list , "SKU" => wpsc_product_sku(), "Quantity" => $product_data['meta']['_wpsc_stock'][0], "Size" => $rowsize['meta_value'], "Color" => $rowcolor['meta_value'], "Manufacturer" => $rowmenu['meta_value'] );
    $i++;           
    endwhile;

     }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why foreach and while loop are not looping all the products. They are looping only the first 7-10 items, although when I check the returned number of products, it's around 60 items. My questions is, how to fix my code to loop over all the products? please help, and thanx in advance.

Comment: The default is [10 posts per page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105048/wp-query-default-number-of-posts). Try adding `'posts_per_page' => -1` to your `$wpec_args`.

Comment: Thanx, please make it as answer so I can upvote it :)

Comment: C'est fait, merci!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default number of posts for [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) is [ten posts per page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105048/wp-query-default-number-of-posts).

Try adding `'posts_per_page' => -1` to your `$wpec_args`:

```
$wpec_args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type'   => 'wpsc-product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'wpsc_product_category' => $wpec_term_slug
);
```